# problem in accessing json parameters

Tags: json, extjs, jsonstore

I have to use json file like this:

```
({"weather":{"city":"Paris", "country":"France"}})
```

I write a JsonStore as:

```
root : "weather",
fields : ['city', 'country']
```

I cant access them like:

```
myStore.on('load', function(store, records, options) {
alert(records[0].get('city'));
}
```

but how can I access them because my json file doesn't have bracket

another case is when I want to access somthing like this:

```
({"data":{"weather":[{ "city" : "Paris", "country" : [{"value" : "France"}] }]}})
```

I define root as "data.weather"

```
fields:['city','country']
```

but I cant access value of country

please describe json file parsing or is there a way to load json file as plain/text?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with extjs but I'll give this a shot since it doesn't seem to be very specific to the framework.

You can't index into `records` because you don't have an array in your JSON. I'd imagine if you used `records.get('city')`, you'd get `Paris`.

Comment: Agreed, in your first example, the .Weather object doesn't contain an array.